# Is it possible to modify a function itself when its property function is called?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to do this:

```
someFunction() // do something

someFunction.somePropertyFunction()

someFunction()  // Now someFunction is modified; it should now exhibit a different behaviour
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I'm not looking for what @Kolink was suggesting.  Basically I want to augment a function's functionality by calling one of it's property function.

Specifically, I need to: 1. have access to the original function inside my property function (which is entirely doable using `this`), and 2. bind a new function to the original function's name (which I'm not sure if it's possible).

Just to be clear, I don't have access to the internal definition of the function that I want to augment. I want to attach a function to Function.prototype (so that it will be available as a property of the function that I want to augment), and then I will call func.augmentThis(), and then `func` should be augmented. But I'm not sure how, hence the question :P

Comment: could you explain further with a short example?

Comment: You mean, you just want to change the value of a property in the function?

Comment: You can't alter the `function` definition. You can set `someFunction` to a new `function`. But, being `new`, it won't have the same properties/methods, like `somePropertyFunction`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski But if the function now has the new functionality, you won't need the function that sets this new functionality any more.

Comment: @MrLister That assumes `somePropertyFunction` and similar are only useful once and don't need to be called again. Otherwise, there's a chance of finding the property `undefined` after the 1st call.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski You're right, but the OP's example indicates that he only needs to do it once. Depending on his needs, it might be better to modify a _different_ function, and to have this function call the other one. then you can do it as often as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Easily. Here's an example:

```
var derp = 123;
someFunction = function() {alert(derp);};
someFunction.somePropertyFunction = function() {derp = 456;};

someFunction(); // alerts 123
someFunction.somePropertyFunction();
someFunction(); // alerts 456
```

Okay, that's an oversimplified example, but yeah, it's entirely possible.

Comment: I believe that he asks if it's possible without a dependency to an outside scoped variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is whether a function attached as a property to another function has a way to access the function to which it is attached, the answer is no. After all, the same function could be attached to any number of functions of objects.

So one alternative is to explicitly refer to the "mother" function within the function that is attached to it and intended to change its behavior:

```
function f (n) {  alert (n + f.offset); }
f.offset = 0;
f.change_offset = function (i) { f.offset = i; };

f (1);                  //1
f.change_offset (100);
f (1);                  //101
```

Here, `f` is hard-wired into the definition of `change_offset`. If this bothers you, or you want something slightly more general, write a little routine to set a function as a property on another function, while binding its `this` to the function being attached to:

```
function set_func_as_func_prop ( propname, func_to_set, func_to_set_on ) {
    func_to_set_on[propname] = func_to_set.bind(func_to_set_on);
}
```

Now you can write the function more generally

```
function change_offset (i) {
    this.offset = i;
}
```

and set it on `f` or any other function.

```
set_func_as_func_prop ("change_offset", change_offset, f);
set_func_as_func_prop ("change_offset", change_offset, g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of:

```
function someFunction() {
    return realFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}

function someFunctionA(name) {
    return 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
}

function someFunctionB(name) {
    return 'Goodbye, ' + name + '...';
}

var realFunction = someFunctionA;

someFunction.somePropertyFunction = function () {
    realFunction = someFunctionB;
};
```

Comment: This is what Aadit was suggesting, but now what I wanted.  See my comment on his answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. It's not recommended, but it's possible. For example:

```
function a() {
    alert("a");
}

function b() {
    alert("b");
}

function c() {
    return c.f.apply(this, arguments);
}

c.f = a;

c.toggle = function () {
    c.f = c.f === a ? b : a;
};
```

Now let's test it:

```
c();        // alerts "a"
c.toggle();
c();        // alerts "b"
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LwKM3/

Comment: This is very clever.  However in my use case I don't have access to the internal definition of the function that I want to augment.  I want to attach a function to `Function.prototype` (so that it will be available as a property of the function that I want to augment), and then I will call `func.augmentThis()`, and `func` should be augmented.  But I'm not sure how, hence the question :P

Comment: @DerekChiang Alright, two things - first, __don't attach a function to `Function.prototype`__. If you want to attach it to `func` then directly attach it to `func`. Second, if you can't modify the definition of the function you want to augment then there's not much you can do. However my answer will still works. Say you want to augment the function `func`, then you simply do `c.f = func` and modify the `toggle` function as you require to. Nevertheless if you need to employ such hacks in the first place then your code design is extremely bad. I'm sure you'll be able to think of a better way. =)

Comment: @AaditMShah The OP stated what he **wants** to achieve rather than what he **needs to achieve [because his code design is extremely bad]**. Please, try to answer his question instead of jumping to conclusions about the asker's ability. It's annoying even to observers, let alone the person at hand :)

Comment: @finishingmove: What's annoying is that you're jumping to conclusions without reading my comment properly. __I did answer his question__ - "However my answer will still works. Say you want to augment the function `func`, then you simply do `c.f = func` and modify the `toggle` function as you require to." That's more than what you've contributed towards solving the OPs problem, so don't point fingers unless you have a solution (preferably a better solution). In addition I'm entitled to state my concerns. If that bothers you then just ignore it or provide a constructive comment. Good day to you.

Comment: Wow, so incredibly rude for no reason. What is this website becoming... I am not jumping to any conclusions, merely commenting on what is factually present in your comment. Regardless of your constructive contribution in your answer and the first part of the comment, there was no need for the "**if you need to employ such hacks in the first place then your code design is extremely bad**" part. Try to keep it civilized, **please**. This website is not for expressing one's superiority, rather trying to help others.

Comment: @finishingmove I think the sentence "__if you need to employ such hacks in the first place then your code design is extremely bad__" is pretty helpful. It tells the OP that in all probability there's a better way to do what he's trying to do, and in no way does that sentence express my superiority. The only unhelpful comments in this discussion belong to you, and I have no reason nor interest to express how superior I am in comparison to you. So please save your preaching for somebody else.

Comment: I believe my comments are important, because I am part of this community and I don't wish to see it flooded with offensive comments.

Comment: @finishingmove My first comment (in response to the OP) wasn't offensive. In fact the first offensive comment in this discussion was your first comment reprehending my comment. I believe my comments are important, because I am part of this community and I don't wish to see it flooded with offensive comments. Hence my response to you. Fire puts out fire.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33348/discussion-between-finishingmove-and-aadit-m-shah)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to attach a function to `Function.prototype`. Then I need to bind a new function to the original function's name (which I'm not sure if it's possible).

That indeed is impossible, you don't know what refers to the function. And you cannot change the internal representation of a function, which is immutable.

The only thing you can do is to create a new function and return that, to let the caller of your method use it somehow - specifically assigning it to the original variable:

```
somefunction = somefunction.augmentSomehow();
```

Your method for that will look like this:

```
Function.prototype.augmentSomehow = function() {
    var origFn = this;
    return function() {
        // in here, do something special
        // which might include invoking origFn() in a different way
    };
};
```

Comment: This is currently the way I'm going.  However I would like to point out that this approach will create a stack overflow.  Specifically, when you do `var origFn = this` and later you do `someFunction = someFunction.augment()`, `origFn` will actually be binded to the augmented function itself, therefore causing stack overflow when invoked. What I do is `(function(origFunc){ ... }(this))`.  That Way I actually have a snapshot of the original function.  Please let me know if you agree with this.

Comment: No, it does not cause a stack overflow. The `origFn` variable is, like in your IEFE, referring to the function directly ("snapshot"). The `augmentSomehow` function is creating the closure scope already.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I would implement described problem in following way:

```
// defined by somebody else - unknown to developer
var someFunction = function() {
    alert("this is initial behavior");
}

someFunction(); // returns "this is initial behavior"

// defines parent object on which someFunction() is called
var parentObject = this; // returns window object (as called direclty in the
// browser)

// if you are calling someFunction from some object (object.someFunction())
// it would be:
// var parentObject = object;

// augumentThis definition
someFunction.augumentThis = function() {
    var newFunction = function() {
        alert("this is changed behavior");
    };
    parentObject.someFunction.somePropertyFunction = function() {
        parentObject.someFunction = newFunction;
        parentObject.someFunction();
    };
};

someFunction.augumentThis();            // change function behavior
someFunction();                         // "this is initial behavior"
someFunction.somePropertyFunction();    // "this is changed behavior"
someFunction();                         // "this is changed behavior"
```