# Stub functions in an array javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stub a set of functions in javascript, by changing directly the implementation, like this (assume fnOne and stub are functions):

`fnOne = stub;`

This works, however, to simplify the code I would like to add N functions to an array, and then stub them all, like this:

```
function fnOne() {return 'fnOne';}

function fnTwo() {return 'fnTwo';}

let fnArray = [fnOne, fnTwo];

function fnStub() {return 'stub';}

fnArray[0]()
"fnOne"

fnOne();
"fnOne"

fnArray[0] = fnStub()
"stub"

fnOne();
"fnOne" //I wanted to stub fnOne, that was in an array.
```

Is that possible in javascript? I know that I an in fact altering the array, not the function, but I wonder if that is possible somehow.

Comment: `I wanted to stub fnOne` what does that mean?

Comment: No, it is impossible to alter functions in JS, you have to alter the `fnOne` variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to modify a function itself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17609931/1048572)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Arrays only hold references to the functions, so you can't use an array accessor to replace an entire function. Your first attempt with

```
fnOne = stub;
```

is the correct way (although bad practice as well).